# Can I distinct update data with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I make the product stock manage system. That use PHP-HTML-SQL Base.
But, it's have some problem about some product is same in all detail values.
and I want to update the value of them only one,which others same product detail values is not change.
How can i use function like `DISTINCT` in `select` on `update` ??

CODE:

```
UPDATE Product SET Customer = '".$To."' 
WHERE ProductID = '".$ProductID."' 
    AND Size = '".$Size."' 
    AND Colour = '".$Colour."'
```

Thanks for all answer. please tell me if you want more information to solve this :))

Comment: Please add your code what you tried, without that, it is really difficult to tell what you're asking here...

Comment: What do you mean by `DISTINCT` update? Do you mean deleting all the duplicate values that has the same `productid`, `size` and `colour` and leave only one entry?

Comment: Can you suggest me please,what part of code that i should add.

Comment: I want to change detail value in only one duplicate product.Which others  duplicate product is not changed.

Comment: How do you choose which product to update?

Comment: It's same, i don't strict about which product to update.

Comment: The question should be **How to update only one record matching the WHERE clause in an UPDATE statement? In the scenario below, a Product has been sold to a Customer, so I need to record the customer against any, but only one (of many) similar product records.**  There should be an `AND customer is null` though

Comment: I suggest to add some sample data so potential helper could at least test code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem :-

```
update table_name 
set column_value = 'value'
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT   MIN (ROWID)
                              FROM table_name 
                          GROUP BY ROWID, column_value)
```